# Get 5 most recent records for each Number

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPWtc.png) I have a table in Access that has a Part Number and PriceYr and Price associated to each Part Number.There are over 10,000 records and the PartNumber are repeated and has different PriceYr and Price associated to it. However, I need a query to just find the 5 most recent price and date associated with it.
I tried using MAX(PriceYr) however, it only returns 1 most recent record for each PartNumber.

I also tried the following query but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 SELECT Catalogs.PartNumber,Catalogs.PriceYr, Catalogs.Price FROM Catalogs
 WHERE Catalogs.PriceYr in 
(SELECT TOP 5 Catalogs.PriceYr
FROM Catalogs as Temp
WHERE Temp.PartNumber = Catalogs.PartNumber
ORDER By Catalogs.PriceYr DESC)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofGEc.png) that i am trying to get.

Comment: try to use `LIMIT 5`

Comment: Your code should work.  What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?

Comment: @Sirmyself It gives a Syntax error while using LLIMIT 5.

Comment: @ace I just remembered that ms-access does not have `LIMIT` as a query statement, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider a correlated count subquery to filter by a *rank* variable. Right now, you pull top 5 overall on matching *PartNumber* not per *PartNumber*.

```
SELECT main.*
FROM
  (SELECT c.PartNumber, c.PriceYr, c.Price,
          (SELECT Count(*)
           FROM Catalogs AS Temp
           WHERE Temp.PartNumber = c.PartNumber
             AND Temp.PriceYr >= c.PriceYr) As rank
   FROM Catalogs c
  ) As main
WHERE main.rank <= 5
```

Comment: I am not trying to count the number of records. I need to display the 5 most recent PriceYr in correspondance to the Part number.

Comment: @ace then instead of `main.*`, select only the data you need to display like this : `SELECT main.PartNumber, main.Price, main.PriceYr FROM...`

Comment: This is not a simple count of records. Did you try running this solution? `COUNT()` is to produce a *rank* variable based on value of *PriceYr* for each *PartNumber*. We use *rank* only to filter for top 5.

Comment: @Sirmyself I tried both these queries. It's returning all of the dataset and not doing anything different.

Comment: @Parfait i tried count(). I just attached the result i am trying to get. This query is returning all the values as it is.

Comment: I can't see how. How does *rank* result? Add it to your `SELECT` and check. Are you filtering outside `main.rank <= 5`?

Answer (score 0):

`MAX()` is an aggregating function, meaning that it groups all the data and takes the maximal value in the specified column. You need to use a `GROUP BY` statement to prevent the query from grouping the whole dataset in a single row.

On the other hand, your query seems to needlessly use a subquery. The following query should work quite fine :

```
SELECT TOP 5 c.PartNumber, c.PriceYr, c.Price 
    FROM Catalogs c
    ORDER BY c.PriceYr DESC
    WHERE c.PartNumber = @partNumber -- if you want the query to 
                                     -- work on a specific part number
```

(please post a table creation query to make sure this example works)

Comment: This didn't work. It only return 5 records from the entire database. I need to get 5 recent date for each part number.

Comment: @ace You already have an adequate answer from ***parfait***. Mine will work if you search for a particular part number, his will generate a list of all the items. Depending on your needs, you can choose between those two answers.